# How to find the source of email spam from a cPanel account?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, centos-7, cpanel, whm

I am running a WHM server with cPanel on a centos server.
CENTOS 7.2 x86_64 kvm – admin  WHM 58.0 (build 24) cPanel 58.0.24

From time to time there are some cPanel accounts getting hacked and sending spam emails. How should I go about finding the source of the problem and stop it?

Comment: Finding the source of spam is not a realistic goal.  There are literally hundreds of ways to spend spam, that makes identify the "source of the spam", a pointless endever..  If the same accounts are being compromised, the simple solution, terminiate their accounts.

Comment: https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Tips+to+Make+Your+Server+More+Secure

Answer (score 1):

If you have accounts that are being hacked to send spam, I assume they have some sort of spam script installed on their system.

**Before I start**: I purchased [Configserver eXploit Scanner](https://configserver.com/cp/cxs.html) about two years ago, it scans files on the server and helped me identify some spam scripts before they could be used. You may want to look into getting this program too if you experience this problem.

If this is indeed the case, [this guide](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/exim/find-spam-script-location-with-exim) is quite useful in resolving the issue. It's helped me find files that are sending large amounts of mail a few times already.

It boils down to the following:

**1.** Run the following command. It gives you a list of directories from which emails were sent. This searches your `exim_mainlog` (located at `/var/log/exim_mainlog` by default). If the spam was sent long ago, it's possible that the log file was rotated since then, and you will not be able to find the directories using this command. Try finding the old log file and running the first `grep` command on that instead.

```
grep cwd /var/log/exim_mainlog | grep -v /var/spool | awk -F"cwd=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

**2.** Go to the directories returned by the command above and inspect the files in there. In my experience most of these spam scripts use pretty obvious file names, but it won't hurt to inspect any files you're not sure about.

**3.** Inspect the Apache access log to find who's calling the script, this command lists all IP's that accessed the file in ascending frequency.

```
grep "<scriptname>" /home/<username>/access-logs/<domain>.<tld> | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -n
```

**4.** It's also possible that the command is executed using a cron job. Use this command to inspect the users' cron jobs.

```
crontab -l -u <username>
```

**5.** Take appropriate action

You may choose to suspend the account, block IP addresses that accessed the script or remove the content. Do whatever you feel is the best solution for you.